# Fixed effects vs first differences when $T = 2$

Tags: paneldata

My understanding is that fixed effects and first differences are numerically equivalent when $T = 2$ (i.e. we have a panel dataset with two time periods).

When I checked this with an example, it seemed that they are equivalent if one runs first differences without a constant, but different if one runs first differences with a constant. Can I confirm that the equivalence does indeed hold if and only  'first differences' means 'first differences without a constant'?

Although this isn't my main question, I would also be interested to learn whether a constant is generally included in first differenced regressions. It seems to me that, since the constant from the original data generating process gets 'differenced out', it makes sense not to include one.